# Vue: Components added through "v-for" ignore flexbox layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I am trying to have navigation controls displayed horizontally in the upper right hand section of the screen. The following works and displays with each item in a row:

```
<template>
    <div id="navControlPanel">
        <div id="controls">
            <NavControl />
            <NavControl />
            <NavControl />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #navControlPanel{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background: purple;
    }

    #controls{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

yet this does not, and instead displays with them in a column:

```
<template>
    <div id="navControlPanel">
        <div id="controls" v-bind:key="control.id" v-for="control in controls">
            <NavControl v-bind:control="control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

NavControl:

```
<template>
    <div id="navControl">
        {{control.id}} //Set to just plain text when not dynamically binded
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    #navControl{
        width: 30pt;
        height: 30pt;
        background: blue;
        border-radius: 1000px;
    }
</style>
```

I can't find a logical reason why these would be any different, unless this is some inherent way Vue works that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that in the first example you got one `div` with multiple components in it:

```
<div id="controls">
   <NavControl />
   <NavControl />
   <NavControl />
</div>
```

The problem is that in the second example you are creating multiple `div` elements with the same id and each of them have nested component inside of it.

Here, in a loop, you create multiple `div` elements with `id="controls"`

```
<div id="controls" v-bind:key="control.id" v-for="control in controls">
      <NavControl v-bind:control="control" />
</div>
```

It ends up being something similar to this:

```
<div id="controls">
   <NavControl />
</div>
<div id="controls">
   <NavControl />
</div>
<div id="controls">
   <NavControl />
</div>
```

You would probably see it better if you inspected your code in the browser tools.

*As a side note: please, keep in mind that if you for whatever reason wanted to do something like this then you would use `class` instead of `id`.*

**Solution:**

What you would want to do instead is to create multiple components inside your `<div id="controls"></div>`.

To do that you would place `v-for` inside the component and not the outer `div`.

```
<NavControl v-for="control in controls" v-bind:control="control" :key="control.id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the actual desired scope, so I will go over both.

If we want multiple `controls` in the template, as laid out, switch `id="controls"` to `class="controls"`:

```
<template>
    <div id="navControlPanel">
        <div class="controls" v-bind:key="control.id" v-for="control in controls">
            <NavControl v-bind:control="control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
...
.controls {
  /* my styles */
}
```

If the `v-for` is out of scope, and we only want this ran on those items on `NavControl`:

```
<template>
    <div id="navControlPanel">
        <div class="controls">
            <NavControl
               v-for="control in controls"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```